# combine rows according to columns into new columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to combine rows according to their rows (a simple example below based on row'id'):

```
id  unit    amount
1    m        10
1    kg       3
2    m        4
3    number   5
3    kg       7
3    m        6
```

I want it converted to:

```
id  unit    amount   unit   amount   unit   amount
1    m        10      kg      3
2    m        4
3    number   5       kg      7       m        6
```

which stores information in new same name rows.
I understand `groupby` and `join` could combine the rows into the preexisted columns but how to store them into new created ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot`:

```
df.assign(col=df.groupby('id').cumcount()).pivot('id', 'col') 
       unit           amount          
col       0    1    2      0    1    2
id                                    
1         m   kg  NaN   10.0  3.0  NaN
2         m  NaN  NaN    4.0  NaN  NaN
3    number   kg    m    5.0  7.0  6.0
```

If You want it exactly like you said then:

```
(df.assign(col=df.groupby('id').cumcount())
   .pivot('id', 'col').reorder_levels([1,0], axis =1)
   .sort_index(axis=1).droplevel(0, axis=1).reset_index())
 
   id  amount    unit  amount unit  amount unit
0   1    10.0       m     3.0   kg     NaN  NaN
1   2     4.0       m     NaN  NaN     NaN  NaN
2   3     5.0  number     7.0   kg     6.0    m
```

if you like, you can use `pivot_wider` from `pyjanitor`:

```
import janitor
df.assign(col=df.groupby('id').cumcount()).pivot_wider('id', 'col')

   id  unit_0 unit_1 unit_2  amount_0  amount_1  amount_2
0   1       m     kg    NaN      10.0       3.0       NaN
1   2       m    NaN    NaN       4.0       NaN       NaN
2   3  number     kg      m       5.0       7.0       6.0
```